# How to group by multiple column with same name of different entity in EF Core - C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I need to join three entities from which I need to sum one column and the name of the column is same in two entity. In sql I can achieve this by using following query

```
select 
     a.ObjectHeadId,
     a.DepartmentId, 
     b.Name as ObjectHeadName,
     c.Name as DepartmentName,
     SUM(BudgetEstimate) 
 from ConsolidatedAppendix1s a
 inner join ObjectHeads b on b.ObjectHeadId=a.ObjectHeadId
 inner join Departments c on a.DepartmentId=c.DepartmentId
 group by a.ObjectHeadId, a.DepartmentId, b.Name, c.Name
```

While trying same in EF Core I am doing like this

```
               consolidatedAppendixI = await _context.ConsolidatedAppendix1s
                                      .Include(entity => entity.Department)
                                      .Include(entity => entity.ObjectHead)
               .GroupBy(r => new {
                   r.Department.Name,
                   r.DepartmentId,
                   r.ObjectHeadId,
                   r.ObjectHead.Name
               })
               .Select(a => new 
               {
                   ObjectHeadId = a.Key.ObjectHeadId,
                   DepartmentId=a.Key.DepartmentId
                   BudgetEstimate = a.Sum(r => r.BudgetEstimate),
                   ObjectHeadName= a.Key.Name,
                   DepartmentName = a.Key.Name,

               }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

While doing so it shows **An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name**.

I can achieve this using

```
GroupBy(x=> 1)
```

but the problem here is I cannot be able to get other columns in `Key` while Selecting likewise it is done above for ObjectHeadId, ObjectHeadName etc.

This is because the name in the group by is same even though they are the property of different entity. How to group those column to get the sum or sql equivalent linq query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the properties different names; it is essentially the same thing as the way you used `AS` in your SQL SELECT block:

```
new {
  DeptName =  r.Department.Name,
  DeptId =    r.DepartmentId,     //optional rename
  HeadId =    r.ObjectHeadId,     //optional rename
  HeadName =  r.ObjectHead.Name
})
```

And refer to these new names in the Select. You don't have to rename the `DepartmentId` and `ObjectHeadId` because they're already distinct but I find it makes code neater than to have a mix of renamed and non renamed:

```
new {
  DeptName =  r.Department.Name,
  r.DepartmentId,     
  r.ObjectHeadId,    
  HeadName =  r.ObjectHead.Name
})
```

You're of course free to choose this route if you like!

---

If you do not specify a property name when creating an anonymous type (by writing a name on th left hand side of an `=`), the compiler will infer one from the name of the property whose value you are using. Because you have two properties with the name `Name` (on different objects), the compiler will essentially try and create an anonymous type like this:

```
var x = new {
  Name = thing1.Name,
  Name = thing2.Name
}
```

Of course, this couldn't work because if you said `var y = x.Name` it isn't clear which `Name` you're talking about

---

As an aside,